# How to extract data based on number of duplicate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with mulitple rows. I want to create a new dataset based on number of duplicate rows for a column. For first dataset, i want a dataset of  no duplicate rows, meaning only the row with one value. For second dataset, i want two duplicate rows and three duplicate rows,but only up to the second one. For third dataset, i want a dataset with just three duplicate rows. So as an example, i wrote codes to describe this situation. Let's Say i have a dataframe as such

```
x = {'column1': ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d'],
    'column2': [22000,25000,27000,350,0,3,5,4,312]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
print (df)
```

The first dataset should look like this:

```
x = {'column1': ['d'],
    'column2': [312]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
print (df)
```

Second dataset should look like this:

```
x = {'column1': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
    'column2': [22000,25000,27000,350,3,5]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
print (df)
```

Third dataset should look like this:

```
x = {'column1': ['b','b','b','c','c','c'],
    'column2': [27000,350,0,3,5,4]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
print (df)
```

How would i do this not manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create counter `Series` by counts:

```
x = {'column1': ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d'],
    'column2': [22000,25000,27000,350,0,3,5,4,312]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
print (df)

s = df.groupby('column1')['column1'].transform('size')
#alternative
#s = df['column1'].map(df['column1'].value_counts())
print (s)
0    2
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    1
Name: column1, dtype: int64
```

And then on list comprehension create DataFrames with filter by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
L = [df[s >= i].groupby(['column1',s]).head(i) if i > 1 else g for i, g in df.groupby(s)]
print (L[0])
print (L[1])
print (L[2])
  column1  column2
8       d      312
  column1  column2
0       a    22000
1       a    25000
2       b    27000
3       b      350
5       c        3
6       c        5
  column1  column2
2       b    27000
3       b      350
4       b        0
5       c        3
6       c        5
7       c        4
```

EDIT1: Because solution is more complicated custom function is created and for rows with `3` values is used [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
def func(x, g):
    if x == 1:
        return g
    else:
        df1 = df[s >= x].groupby(['column1',s]).head(x)
        if x == 3:
            return (df1.groupby(['column1',s], group_keys=False)
                       .nth([0, -1])
                       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                       .reset_index())

        else:
            return df1

L = [func(i, g) for i, g in df.groupby(s)]
print (L[0])
print (L[1])
print (L[2])
  column1  column2
8       d      312
  column1  column2
0       a    22000
1       a    25000
2       b    27000
3       b      350
5       c        3
6       c        5
  column1  column2
0       b    27000
1       b        0
2       c        3
3       c        4
```

Comment: These seem like good solution, but how would i make datasets out of this solution?

Comment: You can use `L[0]` for first DataFrame, `L[1]` for second... Similar for second solution `d[1]`, `d[2]`. It is same like use `df1`, `df2`...

Comment: Actually, for the second dataset(L[1]), the conditions were two duplicate rows and three duplicate rows,but ONLY up to the second one.  I think the second part of the condition is missing. I still see three duplicate rows when i try this code on other dataset

Comment: WOW works perfectly, but can i ask you one more thing with little change to condition for third dataset. For the third dataset, i still want rows with three duplicate rows, but just first and last row. How would i do that?

Comment: @Godseph - Only for  3 DataFrame need `{'column1': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'column2': [27000, 0, 3, 4]}` ?

Comment: Yes that is what i want. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to find the `count` of `column1` and find the subset the dataframe which has same count for `column1`

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['column1']).agg({'column2' : 'count'}).reset_index()
for cnt in df2['column2'].sort_values().unique():
    print(df[df['column1'].isin(df2[df2['column2'] == cnt]['column1'])])
```

It will give you the output

```
  column1  column2
8       d      312
  column1  column2
0       a    22000
1       a    25000
  column1  column2
2       b    27000
3       b      350
4       b        0
5       c        3
6       c        5
7       c        4
```